# How to check the length of an object returned by combinations method of itertools module in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the length of the object returned by combinations method of itertools module.

I did this in my code:

```
comb=combinations('aacd',2)
```

When I do

```
 l=list(comb)
 print(l)
```

It returns:

```
[('a', 'a'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('a', 'c'), ('a', 'd'), ('c', 'd')]
```

And when I try to calculate the length of list l:

```
print(len(l))
```

It returns 0.

I am fairly new to python, and I really want to know how can I calculate the length of an object(combinations is returning an object here) which is converted into a list.

Many thanks.

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem.  Are you sure you aren't overwriting `l` between creating it and trying to print its length? [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYk7DoAgDEB3TsEGJE46cxhEjE1KS6CLp6@yGLf3abdcTJvq2blakNKFGYeF2riLzVx3oCTANMyU@C/epZQPt6zBYEQY4ucNpnUg8fhBoVeC6gM "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: It needs to work fine. Can you share all of your code?

Comment: Directly check length. Printing it first may be clearing the generator.

Comment: If what you actually did was `print(len(comb))`, that is indeed 0 because you consumed all of the combinations when you made the list.

Comment: @jasonharper could you please explain this in detail ? Many thanks.